# ticker text does not run really smooth

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate, subtitles

I want to create a ticker text video like the news ticker you see sometimes in TV. So I use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i Transparent_800x20.png  -vf drawtext="fontsize=16:fontcolor=black:fontfile=FreeSansBold.ttf:textfile=deutsch.txt:x=w/2-125*t:y=0" -t 125 output.mp4
```

with a background PNG file and a text file deutsch.txt. However, because of x=w/2-125*t the ticker text is not running smoothly enough. I got it smoother when I increased the time of the video and decreased the 125 to 60. But the total length of the video should be only 125 seconds to show the whole text.

I tried to increase the frames per second from 25 to 35 (with "fps=35"), but it did not really help. And higher fps lead to duplicate frame messages.

Any other suggestions?

Sigbert

Comment: If running on a PC screen, your best bet for a smooth playback is probably 60fps.